# Android Spinners stop working sporadically

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have written and published an app “Sensor Recording” which reads out and displays the measured values of some sensors (position, acceleration, orientation, pressure, etc.).

In one of the activities called “Panel” the values are displayed with different scale units, e.g. speed in m/s, km/h or knots or altitudes in meters or feet. The units are selected by means of Spinners. If I change one of the units e.g. for the speed, all the speed displays shall change their unit accordingly, so that all speed numbers show the same unit - either m/s, km/h or knots. This is handled inside the method “onItemSelected”. Normally, this works fine.

But sporadically, this functionality stops working. When I select one of the Spinners to change a unit, “onItemSelected” is not invoked any more. No Idea why, the effect is not reproducible! How can I track down this malfunction with the debugger in Android Studio? I can’t set breakpoints inside the library code of the operating system.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

And a code snippet:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id)
{
   // set flag accordingly
   int index = -1;
   if (parent == spinnerheightGPS) index = ialtGPS;  //  4 = altitude GPS
   if (parent == spinnerheightQNH) index = ialtQNH;  // 15 = altitude QNH
   if (parent == spinnerspeed5)    index = isog;     //  5 = speed GPS
   if (parent == spinnerspeed11)   index = iavg1;    // 11 = average speed 1

   // update display
   switch (index)
   {
      // altitude units
      case ialtGPS:  //  4
      case ialtQNH:  // 15
         panelFlag[ialtGPS] = pos;
         panelFlag[ialtQNH] = pos;

         spinnerheightGPS.setSelection(pos);
         spinnerheightQNH.setSelection(pos);

         aaltgps.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%1.1f", adaptUnitHeight(altitudeGPS, pos)));
         aaltqnh.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%1.1f", adaptUnitHeight(altitudeQNH, pos)));
         break;

      // speed units
      case isog:     //  5
      case iavg1:    // 11
         FileHandler.panelFlag[isog]  = pos;
         FileHandler.panelFlag[iavg1] = pos;

         spinnerspeed5.setSelection(pos);
         spinnerspeed11.setSelection(pos);

         asog.setText     (String.format(Locale.US, "%1.1f", adaptUnitSpeed(speedGPS, pos)));
         aaverage1.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%1.1f", adaptUnitSpeed(speedAverage, pos)));
         break;

      default:
         break;
   }  // switch index

}  // onItemSelected
```

@inkredusk

This is an extract of onCreate()

```
public class Act07_Panel extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener,
        TextView.OnEditorActionListener
{
    public static final int maxPanels = 18;
    public static int[] panelFlag = new int[maxPanels];

    private Spinner spinnerheightGPS, spinnerheightQNH;
    private Spinner spinnerspeed5, spinnerspeed11;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act07_panel);


        // initialize spinners
        spinnerheightGPS = findViewById(R.id.spinnerheightGPS);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterheight = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_height, R.layout.spinner_format_panel);
        adapterheight.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerheightGPS.setAdapter(adapterheight);
        FileHandler.panelFlag[ialtGPS] = Math.min(FileHandler.panelFlag[ialtGPS], adapterheight.getCount()-1);
        spinnerheightGPS.setSelection(FileHandler.panelFlag[ialtGPS]);
        spinnerheightGPS.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinnerheightQNH = findViewById(R.id.qnh3spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterqnh3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_height, R.layout.spinner_format_panel);
        adapterqnh3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerheightQNH.setAdapter(adapterqnh3);
        FileHandler.panelFlag[ialtQNH] = Math.min(FileHandler.panelFlag[ialtQNH], adapterqnh3.getCount()-1);
        spinnerheightQNH.setSelection(FileHandler.panelFlag[ialtQNH]);
        spinnerheightQNH.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinnerspeed5 = findViewById(R.id.spinnerspeed5);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterspeed5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_speed, R.layout.spinner_format_panel);
        adapterspeed5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerspeed5.setAdapter(adapterspeed5);
        FileHandler.panelFlag[isog] = Math.min(FileHandler.panelFlag[isog], adapterspeed5.getCount()-1);
        spinnerspeed5.setSelection(FileHandler.panelFlag[isog]);
        spinnerspeed5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinnerspeed11 = findViewById(R.id.spinnerspeed11);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterspeed11 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_speed, R.layout.spinner_format_panel);
        adapterspeed11.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerspeed11.setAdapter(adapterspeed11);
        FileHandler.panelFlag[iavg1] = Math.min(FileHandler.panelFlag[iavg1], adapterspeed11.getCount()-1);
        spinnerspeed11.setSelection(FileHandler.panelFlag[iavg1]);
        spinnerspeed11.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        // and some more with the same procedure ...
        // ...

    }  // onCreate
```

and the related spinners.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="spinner_titel">spinner title:</string>

    <string-array name="spinner_height" >
      <item>m</item>
      <item>ft</item>
    </string-array>
    
    <string-array name="spinner_speed" >
      <item>m/s</item>
      <item>km/h</item>
      <item>kts</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you please include the code where you have initialized your spinner and attached the listener?

Comment: See amendments above.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea, how to debug the internal processes of android? In particular the behaviour after selecting one of the spinner items.